# Mongoengine to_json does conver ReferenceField as OIDs

Tags: python, mongoengine

If model contains ListField(db.ReferenceField)) and after querying called `to_json()` ir does not convert children to json, just kept it as OIDs. Is there way to convert (at least to X deep level) children to json easily?

```
"data": {
 "articles": [],
 "category": {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5224905453f0462f5458a724"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "$oid": "5224905453f0462f5458a725"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "5224905453f0462f5458a726"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "5224905453f0462f5458a727"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "5224905453f0462f5458a728"
    }
  ],
...........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no, it converts the documents to [extended json](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) format.  If you want to wrap embedded documents then you would have to handle this as a totally custom format and deal with the converting and parsing manually.

Comment: can you please please show how to convert those oid, let's say to one of the fields to where those oid's are refering?  let's say I want to replace my `to_users = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField(User))` with actual value of field `username` from collection `User`

Answer (score 10):

Instead of to_json() ( You can override to_json in your document)  , use to_mongo() to get a SON object , then update the SON object fields (just like a dict object), for each referencefield items replace them with item.to_mongo() , and finally return bson.json_util.dumps( SON obj).

```
#override
def to_json(self):
   data = self.to_mongo()
   for i in range(len(data['children'])):
        data['children'][i]= self.children[i].to_mongo()
   return bson.json_util.dumps(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for this good answer. I combined it with the CustomQuerySet class in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23990828/3073422 for a solution that works for querysets too. Also note that it should be `def to_json(self):`