# How to access other class elements from ReferenceField in Mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

```
class User(db.Document):
    email = db.StringField(required=True)
    first_name = db.StringField(max_length=50)

    ref = db.ReferenceField('Post')



class Post(db.Document):
    title = db.StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
    tags = db.ListField(db.StringField(max_length=30))
```

I have two classes User and Post. I want to access the elements of User class from Post class(ref) using:

```
User.objects.first().ref.title
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'
```

How do I do it? How to access all elements and not just one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do that with a reference field, you would have to take the reference and find the object via:

```
Post.objects(id=User.objects().first().ref["id"]).first().title
```

You could though if you made Post an EmbeddedDocument of User and you call for the User objects with select_related like:

```
User.objects().first().select_related(1).ref.title
```

Or you could overwrite the json interpretation as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23990828/493685